# Why is two way Swiper JS control not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, swiper.js

I am unable to get any kind of control going between 2 Swipers, however they are rendering as expected, just NO working controller functionality. A similar question has been asked and NOT yet answered  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63928809/how-to-fix-bug-with-two-way-controll-swiper-in-reactjs)

I would like to get two way control, where sliding in either direction on any of the 2 Swipers results in an equivalent sliding on the other Swiper. My code is as follows:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import SwiperCore, { Controller } from 'swiper';
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';

// Import Swiper styles
import 'swiper/swiper.scss';
import 'swiper/components/controller/controller.scss';

import './styles.css';

// install Swiper's Controller component
SwiperCore.use([Controller]);

const App = () => {
  // store swiper instances
  const [firstSwiper, setFirstSwiper] = useState(null);
  const [secondSwiper, setSecondSwiper] = useState(null);

  const slides = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i += 1) {
    slides.push(
      <SwiperSlide key={`slide-${i}`}>
        <img
          src={`https://picsum.photos/id/${i + 1}/500/300`}
          style={{ listStyle: 'none' }}
          alt={`Slide ${i}`}
        />
      </SwiperSlide>
    );
  }

  const slides2 = [];
  for (let i = 9; i < 14; i += 1) {
    slides2.push(
      <SwiperSlide key={`slide-${i}`}>
        <img
          src={`https://picsum.photos/id/${i + 1}/500/300`}
          style={{ listStyle: 'none' }}
          alt={`Slide ${i}`}
        />
      </SwiperSlide>
    );
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Swiper
        onSwiper={setFirstSwiper}
        controller={{ control: secondSwiper }}
        slidesPerView={1}>

        {slides}
      </Swiper>

      <Swiper
        onSwiper={setSecondSwiper}
        controller={{ control: firstSwiper }}
        slidesPerView={1}>

        {slides2}
      </Swiper>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else runs into this, and is simply using Vanilla JS:
See: https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api
Specifically:

> Controller Methods
> Properties swiper.controller.control  Swiper
>
> Pass here another Swiper instance or array with Swiper instances that
> should be controlled by this Swiper

```
firstSwiper.controller.control = secondSwiper;  
secondSwiper.controller.control = firstSwiper;
```

Would be the appropriate syntax for two-way control.

Answer (score 1):

So apparently there is NO issue with the code, rather the controller implementation as is does NOT work on version `swiper@6.4.5`, I've tested it on an earlier version `swiper@6.0.2` and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Using React, you can use `useRef` and `useLayoutEffect` like this:

```
import React, { useLayoutEffect, useRef } from "react";
// Import Swiper React components
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";

// Import Swiper styles
import "swiper/css";
import "swiper/css/pagination";
import "swiper/css/navigation";

import "./styles.css";

// import required modules
import { Pagination, Navigation, Controller } from "swiper";

export default function App() {
  const swiper1Ref = useRef();
  const swiper2Ref = useRef();

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    swiper1Ref.current.controller.control = swiper2Ref.current;
    swiper2Ref.current.controller.control = swiper1Ref.current;
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <Swiper
        onSwiper={(swiper) => {
          swiper1Ref.current = swiper;
        }}
        slidesPerView={1}
        spaceBetween={30}
        loop={true}
        pagination={{
          clickable: true
        }}
        navigation={true}
        modules={[Pagination, Navigation, Controller]}
        className="mySwiper"
      >
        <SwiperSlide className="slide">Slide 1</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide className="slide">Slide 2</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide className="slide">Slide 3</SwiperSlide>
      </Swiper>
      <Swiper
        onSwiper={(swiper) => {
          swiper2Ref.current = swiper;
        }}
        slidesPerView={1}
        spaceBetween={30}
        loop={true}
        pagination={{
          clickable: true
        }}
        navigation={true}
        modules={[Pagination, Navigation, Controller]}
        className="mySwiper2"
      >
        <SwiperSlide className="slide">Slide 1</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide className="slide">Slide 2</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide className="slide">Slide 3</SwiperSlide>
      </Swiper>
    </>
  );
}
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/swiperjs-two-way-control-mzvudu

Comment: This a good answer since we're on v8 and you example work like a charm, the only thing is you can just write with `useEffect` since it's work too, quoting from react docs:

"we recommend starting with `useEffect` first and only trying `useLayoutEffect` if that causes a problem."